# Find_all function returning multiple strings that are separated but not delimited by a character

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Background: I am pretty new to python and decided to practice by making a webscraper for https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/markets/stocks/a-z which would allow me to pull the company name, ticker, origin, and sector. I could then use this in another scraper to combine it with more complex information. The page is separated by 2 indexing methods- one to select the first letter of the company name (at the top of the page and another for the number of pages within that letter index (at the bottom of the page). These two tags have the class = "pagination" identifier but when I scrape based on that criteria, I get two separate strings but they are not a delimited list separated by a comma.

Does anyone know how to get the strings as a list? or individually? I really only care about the second.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# open the source code of the website as text 
source = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/markets/stocks/a-z/x'

page = requests.get(source).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

for tags in soup.find_all('ul', class_='pagination'):
   
    tags_text = tags.text
    print(tags_text)
```

Which returns:

```
0-9ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX (current)YZOther
«123»
```

When I try to split on /n:

```
tags_text = tags.text.split('/n')
print(tags_text)
```

The return is:

```
['\n0-9ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX (current)YZOther']
['«123»']
```

Neither seem to form a list. I have found many ways to get the first string but I really only need the second.

Also, please note that I am using the X index as my current tab. If you build it from scratch, you might have more numbers in the second string and the word (current) might be in a different place in the first list.

THANK YOU!!!!

Edit:
Cleaned old, commented out code from the source and realized I did not show the results of trying to call the second element despite the lack of a comma in the split example:

```
tags_text = tags.text.split('/n')[1]
print(tags_text)
```

Returns:

```
File, "C:\.....", line 22, in <module>
tags_text = tags.text.split('/n')[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You could try `tags.text.splitlines()`, also you probably want `\n` not `/n`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was using print() when I should have been using return, .apphend(), or another term to actually do something with the value...